# Active Admin strip form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

Is it possible to [`strip`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/strip) forms' input fields in Rails [Active Admin](https://activeadmin.info/index.html)?

e.g:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :attr, as: :string
    end
  end
```

I tried `string_options` to copy [`datepicker_options`](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#datepicker) mechanism, but no luck.

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :attr, as: :string, string_options: { strip: true }
    end
  end
```

I did not found anything in the doc.

**note**: strip means removing empty spaces from the beginning and end of a string.

```
"  clean input  ".strip # "clean input"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One not recommended way is:

```
f.input :attr, as: :string, html_options: { value: f.object.attr.try(:strip) }
```

But then you might interfere with formtastic internals, or with localization or someting else. This imho is the *better* way: use a before validation hook in your ActiveRecord model:

```
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :strip_whitespace
   
  def strip_whitespace
    self.attr = self.attr.try(:strip)
  end
end
```